# Ionic 2/3 - I can't download image from url

Tags: image, download, ionic2, ionic3

I have a problem with download image using url. The application alert me that image has been downloaded but nothing in the gallery. Here my steps and codes:

1st: I installed these plugins

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/

2nd: In the Medule:

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
...
providers:[
   ...
   FileTransfer,
   //FileUploadOptions, 
   FileTransferObject,
   File,
]
```

finally: In my home page

```
 import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from 
 '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
 import { File } from '@ionic-native/file'; 
 ...
 export class HomePage {
    fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    constructor(... , private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File) {}
    ...

    download(imgURL){
       this.fileTransfer.download(image.img, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.jpg').then((entry) => {
          alert('download complete: ' + entry.toURL())
       }, (error) => {
          // handle error
       });
    }
 }
```

So, Is there any wrong thing in my steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could download by add/edit these few codes

1st: I defined cordova in the top of ts

```
declare var cordova:any;
```

then: I did these changes in the download function

```
download(imageURL) {
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
let targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+ "download/"+moment().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmsss")+".jpg";
fileTransfer.download(imageURL, targetPath, true).then((entry) => {
  alert('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
}, (error) => {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    });
}
```

but my answer still not completed because the image didn't save to gallery. So, any helps ?

**Note: I have already the path of downloaded image "entry.toURL()" but how can I view the image in the gallery ?**